# Broken "Learn More" link on Suggested edits page

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits

I have noticed a broken link on [Suggested Edits history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history) page.

I can see "Learn More" text as a link, which is clickable but it doesn't take the user anywhere.

[image: Learn More text visible as link but not taking user anywhere]

I tried checking the same link on different browsers and ended up with same results.

Comment: It does show https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Kcs.png when you are on the review "tab" but on the stats and history tab the click event for that "learn more" button (that is what it is) doesn't get wired up. It might be intentional as that dialog doesn't have guidance for stats or history. Maybe the fix is to hide that whole sentence on the stats and history page?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364367/284827

Comment: Already reported here: [New onboarding for review queues](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/364060/289905).